How to add structured data for rich snippets in Angular 17 standalone components with SSR?
I am using Angular 17 with SSR configuration enabled and complete standalone component architecture and want to insert structured data in different components for rich snippet and better SEO crawling.
example:

I searched for different ways to do it and came across few ideas of doing it like bellow:
constructor(private meta:Meta){
meta.addTag({name:'application/ld+json' , content:JSON.stringify(STRUCTURED_DATA_OBJECT)});
}

But this is not what I want , I want to add the structured data object inside <script> tag separate for each standalone components.

It is very confusing to me what exactly you are trying to achieve. Please clarify.

Preview the image i have shared in the question for better understanding .
<script type="application/ld+json"> {   "@context": "http://schema.org",   "@type": "Article",   "headline": "Your Article Headline",   "description": "Brief description of your article",   "author": {     "@type": "Person",     "name": "Your Name"   }   // ... other structured data properties } </script>

and you want to have something similar, but for source code of your components? Also does the meta.addTag() function work in general, or not?

@JSONDerulo yes . I want to achieve this in each and every standalone components .
Yes the 'meta.addTag()function works , but it adds the content in the meta tag of the component source code , not inside the
@AnkitKhatri please raise a issue in angular github, I don't think its currently possible, of course you can add a script tag using angular, but it won't work in SSR because document is undefined on the server.

@NarenMurali I think i got a way to do that using Renderer2 from angular/core and DOCUMENT from angular/common

@AnkitKhatri If you are able to generate using SSG then you are awesome, if not its a good idea to raise a feature request with the angular team. Only SSG content is read by web crawlers, so you need to check that first, if the script tag gets generated

@NarenMurali My requirement was to dynamically add scripts containing structured data in each standalone components . And with this methodology , I got the work done . Now i can have scripts for each individual components separately .

@AnkitKhatri the reason you do this is for google to read this content, this will happen only if your component has SSG enabled for those components

@NarenMurali yes obviously ssg is enabled for those components.

@AnkitKhatri run a build, if the script that gets inserted, post an answer it will help someone! if so, nice find! :)

I have found a way to do that using Renderer2
See the code below for reference 
Use this code in whichever component you want to add the structured data.
import {Inject, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';


@Component({...})

export class CustomClass implements OnInit{

constructor(private _renderer:Renderer2 , @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document:Document){}

public ngOnInit(){

  let script = this._renderer.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'application/ld+json';
  script.text = `{data}`;  /*Insert the data you want to add*/

  this._renderer.appendChild(this._document.body, script);
  }


@NarenMurali you may check this code , if it works for you then it's great or else we will surely find a way for your issue.

wow, great stuff!
